# Reacord deleted from the database but getting an error :- Request failed with status code 404 using axios, node, mongo and Koa

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, koa

The Data Is Deleted Successfully but I am getting an error with the code GET http://localhost:3000/api/deletetagbyid/5e4d896cea390804241612cd 404 (Not Found).

Can any one please help me actually I am new in react node:- 
Thanx You

```
// Delete Discount Tag Using Axios :-
const handleDelete = async (e, id) => {

    if (confirm("Are you sure. You Want to delete this tag?")) {

        await axios.get("/api/deletetagbyid/" + id).then((result) => {
            console.log(result);
        }).catch(() => {
            console.log('Error Occured');
        });
    }
}

// This is the backend code to delete data with koa js :-
exports.deletetagbyid = (ctx) => {

    let id = ctx.params.id;
    Note.findOne({
        "_id": ObjectID(id)
    }, function (err, docs) {

        if (!docs) {
            ctx.body = 404;
        } else {
            Note.deleteOne({
                _id: id
            }, function (err, obj) {
                if (err) throw err;
                ctx.body = "Deleted SuccessFully";
                console.log(" document(s) deleted");
            });
        }
    })
};

// This is the route for delete data :-
router.get('/api/deletetagbyid/:id', discounttag.deletetagbyid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry , do not use **get** method for deleting the record from database use **DELETE** method

And for your question i think you are calling the delete api two times